# Prove that $ λ^4+ λ^3+ 2 λ^2+ λ+ 1$ cannot be the characteristic polynomial of an adjacency matrix of any simple graph

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

Prove that $ λ^4+ λ^3+ 2 λ^2+  λ+ 1$  cannot be the characteristic polynomial of an adjacency matrix of any simple graph.

Is it because there are no real roots of this equation?

Comment: If simple graph means what I think it means (no loops or multiple edges), then you could use the fact that the adjacency matrix has zeros on its diagonal, so has trace zero.

Comment: Yes simple graph means no loops and multiple edges. thank you

Comment: @user286826: The coefficient of $\lambda^3$ should be $0$ and not $1$.